# How to show loading animation with fancybox?

Tags: fancybox

I got fancybox working but I have this problem:
First, I can't make the loading image appear. And second, if I use a link to show an image on click, sometimes it fails to show it, because of the time it takes to load it (if it were an image instead of a link, it would have been already loaded by the browser, that's why it never fails with images).

In summary, I have a link, when I click it a modal window with an image should appear. Instead, a white box appears. If I reload the page, sometimes the image appears, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: can you write the code where you are using fancybox?

Comment: sorry, I'm using an MVC framework and it would be complicated to paste it here. I'm using fancybox default settings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working some of the time, maybe the problem is elsewhere? Is the picture you are loading particularly large, if you are shift refreshing I have experienced such effects in the past.

Comment: No, its working some of the times because sometimes the browser loads the image in a blink, other times it takes a couple of seconds. I'm pretty sure it's a fancybox problem, not resizing properly 'onComplete' or something. When the image is in the browser's cache it never fails.

Comment: Anyway, I guess it would get fixed if I could make the loading animation appear. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The plugin should take care of that itself, there must be some conflicting code or css etc. preventing it from displaying.